# Unable to center text in a constraint layout away from the image view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a constraint layout whose width is wrapped, and is rendered in a recycler view in a flex layout.

This is what I want.

[image: Desired Image layout]

The text in the image in this example `Noodle Dish.. is to centered below the image, and the prices`.

The prices are to be positioned to the right of the image, and nearer to the margins but above the text at the bottom.

What I am generating is this

[image: Actual image]

The bottom text for the larger views are not centered, and the prices are cutting into the image. The prices are to be positioned at the after the image, and closer to the end margins.

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>

        <variable
            name="product"
            type="com.myproject.mobile.data.Product" />
    </data>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        style="@style/CardView"
        android:visibility="@{product != null ?  View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/product_image_url"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/product_image_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/product_image_height"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:imageUrl="@{product.imageUrl}" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/product_price_container"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:gravity="end"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_original_price"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/strikethrough"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance"
                    app:inUSD="@{product.originalPrice}"
                    tools:text="$5.00"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_price"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Secondary"
                    app:inUSD="@{product.price}"

                    tools:text="$5.00"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_display_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:maxWidth="@dimen/text_display_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="@{product.displayName}"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/product_price_container"
                tools:text="Onion flavoured rings"
                />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

**ISSUES**

1. Bottom text is not centered for all layouts
2. The prices are not placed to the end of the image, and towards the end

**DESIRED OUTCOME**

1. Bottom text to be centered for all layouts
2. The prices to be placed to the end of the image, and towards the end

Answer (score 0):

**1. Bottom text is not centered for all layouts**

Within *ConstraintLayout*, views are centered between their constraints. For the product named, constrain the product name *TextView* to the start and the *end* of the parent to center horizontally in the parent. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#CenteringPositioning).

**2. The prices are not placed to the end of the image, and towards the end**

It is not clear exactly what the issue is here. Is it that the *CardView* does not stretch completely across or that the prices cut into the image when the *CardView* is not wide enough to accommodate both? Or something else?

Comment: how can i fix this? I am trying to the view in such a way that it means the desired set up. I don't know what I am doing wrong. 

I am hoping that someone can help me set up the layout in a way which will render the views the way I would like them to be.

Comment: Answer to your second question is that prices cut into the image. I don't want that.

Comment: @Kartik In you example the image and the price will not fit horizontally in the allowed space. When that is the case what should happen? You can reduce the number of products on each line or shrink the width of the image or price.